# Outlook 2016 COM Add-in Load Behaviour has status 'Removed'?

Tags: outlook, add-in

We have an odd issue. We have an Outlook Add-in that is not properly loading. As such that is not uncommon as Outlook is notorious of disabling add-in and having an issue with load behavior; we have seen that for years with setting the load behavior to "3" in Regedit, Add-in resiliency and do not disable options intervention needed  (https://support.boyum-it.com/hc/en-us/articles/208245778-CRM-for-Outlook-Add-In-keeps-disabling)

But now we have a new odd case that we have seen before. The Load Behaviour is instead of the normal "Unloaded" it is set as "Removed" and the Com-add-in is unchecked
[image]

Further More the LoadBehaviour DWORD entry does not exist at all on the customer's system (Again never seen that)[image]

Facts:
- Add-in is running on over 2000 other installations around the world so doubt it is some sort of code error
- If the add-on is checked in the list the Add-in start-up fine (but is unchecked again after a restart of Outlook)

Has anyone seen this behavior before and know how to resolve/troubleshoot further?

Comment: Is there any antivirus software used? Could you specify the exact Outlook version used? Can you reproduce this issue with a sample VSTO add-in?

Comment: There is Antivirus on the machine but does not seem it did something bad to the files according to it's logs. It is Office 365 latest version (they auto-update all the time). Not tried with sample VSTO but other Add-ins are on the machine and working

Comment: Please let us know whether a problem is reproducible with a newly created sample add-in.

Comment: Have tested with a Sample Add-in and it has no issues. Also got the customer to switch to English Outlook and the Danish translation is apparently terrible.. It does not say Load Behavior is "Removed"... It says "Unloaded"

Comment: This is just getting stranger and stranger... If Outlook is run as Administrator it works... In a normal user context, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your add-in fires an exception at runtime if a sample add-in works correctly.
Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the `Startup` event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the `Startup` event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2019) article.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The add-in is not hard disable (not in the Disabled items list). It is possible to re-enable it in the COM Add-in list and then the Add-in works as expected. But if you restart the add-in yet again goes into Unloaded state

Comment: Is it soft disabled?